# if grep value greater than 1000 then

Tags: bash, shell

I want to grep "priority=" in a file where the value of "priority=" is greater than 1000.

I tried something like this:

```
if grep -q "priority=[ >1000 ]" file; then
    echo "[!] Unnatural priority"
fi
```

e.g. `<intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">`

Comment: Can you give a sample output of `grep "priority=" file`

Comment: Can't you pipe to awk if you just want output if there's a problem? What problem are you really trying to solve? Do you want line numbers for the place with invalid values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lne 'print "[!] Unnatural priority" if /priority="(\d+)"/ && $1 > 1000'
```

Capture the digits in priority="X" and print the warning if the value is greater than 1000.

You can also do this in native bash if you want:

```
while read -r line; do 
    if [[ $line =~ priority=\"([[:digit:]]+)\" ]] && (( BASH_REMATCH[1] > 1000 )); then
        echo "[!] Unnatural priority"
    fi
done < file
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try using a regular expression to require a pattern that resembles a number greater than one thousand:

```
grep -q --regexp="priority=\"[1-9][0-9]\{3,\}\"" file
```

This should match the case where `priority=` is followed by at least four digits and the first digit is non-zero.

Comment: Apologies, first version forgot to escape the curly braces. This edited version is tested and returns the matches as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
(( $(grep -oP 'priority\s*=\s*"\s*\K(\d+)' file) > 1000 )) && echo "warning"
```

Need a relatively new grep with `-P` perl regex support. The:

- `\K` (variable look behind) matches, but kills everything before it from the result, so it prints only the capture group `(\d+)`

of course, you can use perl too,

```
perl -nlE 'say $1 if /priority="\K(\d+)/' <<< '<intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">'
```

prints

```
2147483647
```

or sed

```
sed 's/.*priority="\([0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/' <<< '<intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">'
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` will make this easy:

```
$ cat file | awk -F '=' '$2 > 1000 {print $0}'
```

Assuming that there's only one `=` on each line of course.

Comment: This breaks if the value after "priority=" has trailing non number characters. e.g. "priority=1____"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - Checking version string that needed to be "Version 2.32" or later. My grep (embedded BusyBox) doesn't support -P option or {n}, so using basic grep:

```
grep "Version 2\.3[2-9]\|2\.[4-9][0-9]\|[3-9]\.[0-9][0-9]"
```